# Join Two arrays of objects by Id and group by property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to join 2 arrays of objects (files X counts) using the "id" property and then, I want to group by "folder" property adding up all counts for each "folder". In final result I don't want to have "id" property

**Files Array:**

```
const file = [{
  id: "xxx",
  folder: "A"
},{
  id: "bbb",
  folder: "B"
},{
  id: "ccc",
  folder: "B"
},{
  id: "ddd",
  folder: "C"
},{
  id: "aaa",
  folder: "C"
},{
  id: "ggg",
  folder: "A"
}]
```

**Counts Array:**

```
const counts = [{
  id: "bbb",
  actions: {
    download: 5,
    seen: 10,
    shared: 3
  }
},{
  id: "xxx",
  actions: {
    download: 2,
    seen: 5,
    shared: 8
  }
},{
  id: "ccc",
  actions: {
    download: 7,
    seen: 9,
    shared: 5
  }
},{
  id: "ggg",
  actions: {
    download: 0,
    seen: 2,
    shared: 3
  }
},{
  id: "eee",
  actions: {
    download: 50,
    seen: 55,
    shared: 3
  }
},{
  id: "fff",
  actions: {
    download: 5,
    seen: 4,
    shared: 3
  }
}]
```

**Result:**

```
const result = [{
  folder: "A",
  actions: {
    download: 2,
    seen: 7,
    shared: 11
  }
},{
  folder: "B",
  actions: {
    download: 12,
    seen: 19,
    shared: 8
  }
},{
  folder: "C"
}]
```

**My Code:**

```
const join = files.reduce((arr, e) => {
  arr.push(Object.assign({}, e, counts.find(a => a.id == e.id)))
  return arr;
}, [])

join.forEach(function(v){ delete v.id });

const result = Object.values(
                 join.reduce((a, c) => (
                   a[c.folder] = a[c.folder] && a[c.folder].actions?
                   (a[c.folder].actions.download += c.actions.download,
                   a[c.folder].actions.seen += c.actions.seen,
                   a[c.folder].actions.shared += c.actions.shared , 
                   a[c.folder]) :
                   c, a), {}
                 )
               )
```

***Is there a proper way to do it in less lines and more optimized?***

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be to

- Use a Map to map the files to their associated folder, to allow for quick lookup later (in contrast, `.find` is `O(n)`)
- Don't `delete` the `id` properties - instead, use them to find the folder associated with the ID while looping over the counts.
- On each iteration, if a folder doesn't exist for a given ID, continue to stop that iteration immediately. Otherwise, iterate over all the properties of the object in question and merge them with the cumulative results object for that folder.

```js
const file=[{id:"xxx",folder:"A"},{id:"bbb",folder:"B"},{id:"ccc",folder:"B"},{id:"ddd",folder:"C"},{id:"aaa",folder:"C"},{id:"ggg",folder:"A"}],counts=[{id:"bbb",actions:{download:5,seen:10,shared:3}},{id:"xxx",actions:{download:2,seen:5,shared:8}},{id:"ccc",actions:{download:7,seen:9,shared:5}},{id:"ggg",actions:{download:0,seen:2,shared:3}},{id:"eee",actions:{download:50,seen:55,shared:3}},{id:"fff",actions:{download:5,seen:4,shared:3}}];

const foldersById = new Map();
for (const { id, folder } of file) {
  foldersById.set(id, folder);
}
const resultMap = new Map(
  [...foldersById.values()]
    .map(folder => [folder, ({ folder, actions: {}})])
);
for (const { id, actions } of counts) {
  const folder = foldersById.get(id);
  if (!folder) continue;
  const resultActions = resultMap.get(folder).actions;
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(actions)) {
    resultActions[key] = (resultActions[key] || 0) + value;
  }
}
const result = [...resultMap.values()];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: And if i want the result as a dictionary  what would you change ? I mean: { "A": { "actions": { "download: 2, "seen": 7, "shared": 11}}, ...  Would you add a line to transform last Array of Objects into a Dictionary how is it done on this [Website](https://dev.to/devtronic/javascript-map-an-array-of-objects-to-a-dictionary-3f42)

Comment: Use `Object.fromEntries` and call `.entries` on the Map, I suppose?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))" :(

Comment: eg `Object.fromEntries([...resultMap.entries()])` or just use an object to start with instead of a Map